# Unable to get Azure Blob Client StartCopyFromUriAsync to complete even with WaitForCompletionAsync

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, quickbooks-online

I'm writing a console app to export "Attachables" from the Quickbooks API for a data migration project. I've tried the code below with *and* without the cancellation token. I either get an Exception or get an error stating that "The operation has not completed yet.".  The BlobCopyStatus is pending until the exception is thrown.

I'm trying to download over 16k files, and 15k+ worked just fine using some similar code.  I've been trying to troubleshoot why a segment can't be downloaded.

I can't seem to find many examples.  Any ideas?

```
CancellationTokenSource cToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
cToken.CancelAfter(30000);
        
var status = await blobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceUri, null, cToken.Token);

if (!status.HasCompleted)
{
    var props = blobClient.GetProperties();
    _log.LogInformation($"blob copy status: {props.Value.BlobCopyStatus}");

    await status.WaitForCompletionAsync();
}

return status;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var status = await blobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceUri, null, cToken.Token); 
await status.WaitForCompletionAsync();
```